# How to get a 3D-matrix or cell array efficiently by using vectorized code?

Tags: matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array, vectorization, cell-array

Here is what I want, a 3-D matrix:

```
K = 2:2.5:10;
den = zeros(1,4,4);
for i = 1:1:4
    den(:,:,i) = [1, 5, K(i)-6, K(i)];
end
```

Or, a cell array is also acceptable:

```
K = 2:2.5:10;
for i = 1:1:4
    den{i} = [1, 5, K(i)-6, K(i)];
end
```

But I want to know if there is a more efficient way of doing this using vectorized code like:

```
K = 2:2.5:10;
den = [1, 5, K-6, K];
```

I know the last code will not get what I wanted. But, like I can use:

```
v = [1 2 3];
v2 = v.^2;
```

instead of:

```
v = [1 2 3];
for i = 1:length(v)
    v(i) = v(i)^2;
end
```

to get the matrix I want. Is there a similar way of doing this so that I can get the 3-D matrix or cell array I mentioned at the beginning more efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

You need to "broadcast" the scalar values in columns so they are of the same length as your K vector. MATLAB does not do this broadcasting automatically, so you need to repeat the scalars and create vectors of the appropriate size. You can use `repmat()` for this.

```
K = 2:2.5:10;
%% // transpose K to a column vector:
K = transpose(K);

%% // helper function that calls repmat:
f = @(v) repmat(v, length(K), 1);

%% // your matrix:
den = [f(1) f(5) K-6 K];
```

This should be more optimized for speed but requires a bit more intermediary memory than the loop does.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `reshape` with a 1*3 size:

```
den = reshape([ones(1,length(K));ones(1,length(K))*5; K-6; K],[1 4 length(K)]);
```

I think the used extra memory by `reshape` should be low and constant (dependent only on the length of the vector of new sizes).

Comment: I think `permute` might make more sense than `reshape` here

Comment: I didn't think of `permute` ... The doc mentions that "permute and ipermute are a generalization of transpose (.') for multidimensional arrays". This operation may cost a lot to transpose elements, so I prefer `reshape`, there is no element move (in theory)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the classic line equation `y=a*x+b`, extended to the matrix form:

```
k = 2:2.5:10 ;
fa = [0 0  1 1].' ; %' // "a" coefficients
fb = [1 5 -6 0].' ; %' // "b" coefficients

d(1,:,:) = fa*k + fb*ones(1,4) ;
```

The above is better for clarity, but if you're not bothered you can also pack everything in one line:

```
d(1,:,:) = [0 0  1 1].' * (2:2.5:10) + [1 5 -6 0].' * ones(1,4) ;
```

---

If you need to re-use the principle for many different values of `k`, then you can use an anonymous function to help:

```
fden = @(k) [0 0  1 1].' * k + [1 5 -6 0].' * ones(1,4) ; %// define anonymous function

k = 2:2.5:10 ; 
d(1,:,:) = fden(k) ; %// use it for any value of "k"
```